# Entail - appropriate word for context

Tags: word-choice

Is entail the appropriate word for my context? If not, can you provide me with a better one (and its construction in my sentence)?

> My courses entail studying every single day when I come back from uni.

What I want to express is that my courses require studying every day.

Answer (score 1):

"Entail" is possible, but "require" is a more common word

> My courses require me to study every day when I come back from university.

And there are many many ways to express requirement in English:

> I have to study every day when I come back.

or "I need to" or even "I've got to".

Your format is fairly formal, and might be clearer with a pronoun

> My courses entail me studying everyday.

Comment: I don't think a course can require someone to do something. My courses require [that] I study etc.

Comment: A course can require all sorts of things.  If you don't meet the requirements, you fail the course.  The requirements can be formal "You must attend at least 80% of lessons" or informal  "If you don't do the required reading, you won't be able to understand the lectures".